# Searching through many pcap files with tcpdump

Tags: pcap, tcpdump

I have a bunch of pcap files that I got with tcpdump. I need to search through all of them for specific keywords and record which files contain these strings. Is there a way to automate the search for these keywords using a tcpdump command perhaps?

Comment: maybe a python script using ```dpkt``` module can help you achieve that

Answer (score 3):

Probably the most generic solution using `tshark` would be to run something like:

```
tshark -r file.pcap -Y "frame contains foo"
```

... where `foo` is the string you're searching for.  Refer to the [wireshark-filter man page](https://www.wireshark.org/docs/man-pages/wireshark-filter.html) for more information on filtering using the `contains` and other operators, such as the `matches` operator which supports Perl compatible regular expressions.

Using that command, the output you'll see will be a 1-line summary of each packet matching the filter.  You could tailor the output using a number of methods, but for example, suppose you only wanted to know the frame number of the matching packet, you could run:

```
tshark -r file.pcap -Y "frame contains foo" -T fields -e frame.number
```

Refer to the [`tshark` man page](https://www.wireshark.org/docs/man-pages/tshark.html) for more information on the `-T` and `-e` options, as well as other options which may be of use to you.

Answer (score 1):

There is more powerful version of tcpdump, tshark (it is the command line tool from wireshark package). You could use tshark -T fields|pdml|ps|psml|text to dump packets in format you like, and just grep it. tshark could read tcpdump dumps.

Comment: I'm not quite sure how I would use this. Say I have a capture file (capture.pcap) and I want to search to see if the file contains the keywords "example1" and "example2". How would I use your solution?